# unique string array type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I need to have a type act like this [exam](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1&ssl=3&ssc=80&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBArgdgSwI4wgQQE4YIYgCrjQC8UAzsBgnAOYDaAulAPRNQDGA9gCbQAWEGaADMOGWIhTRylGlGxZcUKAG4AsAChOcclAC2IAKoTUmHCABc45CYX5CUErQDk0qtSgBGJwBooLim5QAExOjCxQAO4IADbRUEIIwFDA-MmEGlo6%20kbW6LZBlvC5prgEkA5QztI%20ftVhrFGxUHAcSQlJKdCgkEA)

```
type uniqueArrayType = string[] // code here ;
const myUniqueArray :uniqueArrayType = ['string 1','string 2'] // will fit the type
const myUniqueArray2 :uniqueArrayType = ['str','str'] // will not fit the type
```

Comment: No, there is no *specific* type that works this way.  You could make a generic type constraint and a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzOkLw), but it's complicated and fragile.  See the other question for more info.

Comment: @jcalz Could you please explain what means the `keyof any[] | I` part in your helper example?

Comment: `I` is the current numeric-like index of the tuple type (something like `"0"` or `"1"` or `"2"`, etc).  For each index `I`, I want to make sure the `I`th element `T[I]` of the tuple is different from all the other ones; so I want to look at all the numeric-like array properties except `I`.  `Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[] I I>` is saying "give me all the keys of `T`, except for the general array ones (like `"length"` or `"pop"`), and except for `I`".